# Blockwise inversion for calculate the inverse of the block matrix?

Tags: matrices, inverse-problems

I have the matrix:

$ M^{-1} =   \begin{pmatrix}X & Y\\\ Z & W\end{pmatrix}$

But I do not know the matrix:

$ M =   \begin{pmatrix}A & B\\\ C & D\end{pmatrix}$

Is possible calculate $ A^{-1} $, no need to invert the matrix $M^{-1}$ (Using Blockwise inversion, it is easy calculate $A^{-1} B = Y U^{-1}$ and $C A^{-1} = Z U^{-1}$, but just $ A^{-1} $, I could not calculate)??

Comment: Check out the second entry in "Properties" [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement).

Comment: @RideTheWavelet that seems irrelevant.  You're pointing to the property *If p and q are both 1 (i.e. A, B, C and D are all scalars), we get the familiar formula for the inverse of a 2-by-2 matrix*.

Comment: You're quite right, sorry about that. Still, if you look right above "Properties" on that page, I think you might find some useful formulas. In particular, $A=(X-YW^{-1}Z)^{-1},$ so $A^{-1}=X-YW^{-1}Z.$

Comment: No don't be sorry about it. It is important to learn to search around for context on one's own too.